# Как запретить ввод текста (изменение уже установленного текста) в TextInput kivy

Tags: python, kivy

У меня есть TextInput,

```
self.text_input = TextInput(hint_text = "Hello Reader!\nPlease select a book and good reading!", 
    focus = False, 
    size_hint = (1, None),
    padding = 20, 
    halign = 'center', 
    )
```

Мне нужно запретить изменение текста пользователем с помощью клавиатуры.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать? Данный эффект мне нужен обратимым (то есть в дальнейшем можно было бы разрешить ввод снова)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте readonly = True

```
self.text_input = TextInput(hint_text = 
"Hello Reader!\nPlease select a book and good reading!", 
    focus = False, 
    size_hint = (1, None),
    padding = 20, 
    halign = 'center',
    readonly = True
)
```